# CSS Grow on hover adds padding to the bottom of an image, how do I stop this from happening?

Tags: css, css-transitions

http://jsfiddle.net/gvBM8/

Whenever you scroll over an image and it grows to the desired effect there is a white border that grows along the bottom as well.  Is there anyway to stop this from happening?

Also, I am new to using CSS3 across multiple browsers, how would I set it up to be moz/IE compatible?

Thank you

HTML

```
<div class="col4 grow"> <a href="#"><img src="http://www.placecage.com/200/300" width="100%"></a>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apply `img` this css property:

```
img {
    display: block;
}
```

Instead of giving to the tag, add a class to those `img` elements. that would be better.

[**Working Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/gvBM8/1/)

Comment: You're freaking awesome.  Thank you.

Comment: @user2997985 np.. please mark it as answer if my post helped you :)

Comment: had to wait 2 minutes :)